# Lowest Eigenvalue of a large sparse matrix without choking up the RAM (Corrected)

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, eigenvalues, sparse-arrays, precision-and-accuracy

I am trying to find the lowest eigenvalue of a large sparse matrix of dimension N (**=$3^n$, where n is number of particles in system** ) using `-Eigenvalues[-H, 1, Method -> {"Arnoldi", "Criteria" -> "RealPart"}]`

**Prob: RAM (16 GB) of my PC chokes up for $n$ more than $n=10$ ($N=59049$).**

What is the way out to perform calculations for little larger $n$ without choking up the RAM and faster computation ?

**Sample Program**

```
s = 1; n = 10;
σI = IdentityMatrix[2 s + 1, SparseArray, WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision];
b0[j_] := N@Sqrt[(s + j)*(s + 1 - j)];
{a, 
-Eigenvalues[-H, 1, Method -> {"Arnoldi", "Criteria" -> "RealPart"}]
```

One solution might be to reduce the overall precision, but either it doesn't work or slows down the computation.

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Even an 1000 by 1000 _dense_ matrix is not large, it takes only 8 megabytes. `arr = RandomVariate[GaussianOrthogonalMatrixDistribution[1, 1000]];
Eigenvalues[arr, -1]` Please show a complete minimal example that fails.

Comment: @Szabolcs, Oh! Sorry, I made a mistake while typing the ques, Now I have edited the ques, Pl have a look again

Comment: Please show a complete minimal example that includes an actual matrix.

Comment: @Szabolcs, ADDED a minimal program

Comment: Your matrix isn't sparse in the sense that it isn't a [`SparseArray`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SparseArray.html) object.

Comment: This is a very good illustration of why one should always, always show a minimal example. 1. This is not a `SparseArray` as the question's original version made it appear. 2. All values are exact, so the Arnoldi method doesn't even apply. 3. Here you show computing all eigenvalues, while in the original example you asked for only the smallest one—this makes a big difference.

Comment: @Szabolcs, Updated the question

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using an actual `SparseArray` and machine precision this evaluates almost immediately with negligible memory footprint.

```
s = 1; n = 10;
b1 = N@Table[s - n, {n, 0, 2 s}];
σx = SparseArray@DiagonalMatrix[b1];
σI = IdentityMatrix[2 s + 1, SparseArray, WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision];
σxx[j_] := KroneckerProduct[## & @@ ConstantArray[σI, j - 1], σx, ## & @@ ConstantArray[σI, n - j]]
H = Sum[(σxx[j]), {j, 1, n - 1}];
Eigenvalues[H, -1, Method -> {"Arnoldi", "Criteria" -> "RealPart"}]
```

Comment: Thanks for excellent answer, I am facing same problem for another `σx` matrix,  I have updated the `σx` Matrix in my question after your posted answer, Could you please help me again and update your answer for updated `σx` matrix ? Thanks Again

Comment: What's the issue? The code from you current version of your question runs without any problems on my machine.

Comment: I am sorry, it is working fine.